# NodeMCU display temperature and control LED from an autorefresh web page

Tags: arduino-ide, led, nodemcu, web

I'm totaly new to Arduino, I'm using ESP2866 NodeMCU and dht22 to display temperature and humidity in a web page, it is autorefresh (using AJAX) and it works perfectly, I wanted to add 2 buttons to it so I can control 2 Leds but when I tried that I couldn't control them and even the values of temperature and humidity stopped refreshing. Can you tell me what is wrong in the code ? here it is :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321

 /*Put your SSID & Password*/
 const char* ssid = "xxx";  // Enter SSID here
 const char* password = "xxx";  //Enter Password here

  ESP8266WebServer server(80);

 // DHT Sensor
 uint8_t DHTPin = D6; 

  // Initialize DHT sensor.
  DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);                

  float Temperature;
  float Humidity;
  float reading;
  float percentage;
  // Auxiliar variables to store the current output state
  String output5State = "off";
  String output4State = "off";

 // Assign output variables to GPIO pins
 const int output5 = 5;
 const int output4 = 4;
 void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 delay(100);

 pinMode(DHTPin, INPUT);
 dht.begin();              

// Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(output5, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(output4, OUTPUT);
 // Set outputs to LOW
 digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
 digitalWrite(output4, LOW);
 Serial.println("Connecting to ");
 Serial.println(ssid);

//connect to your local wi-fi network
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

//check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(1000);
Serial.print(".");
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

server.begin();
Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}
void loop() {

server.handleClient();
}

void handle_OnConnect() {

Temperature = dht.readTemperature(); // Gets the values of the temperature
Humidity = dht.readHumidity(); // Gets the values of the humidity 

//Serial.println(reading); 
String header=SendHTML( Temperature,Humidity,percentage);

server.send(200, "text/html",header); 
// turns the GPIOs on and off
        if (header.indexOf("GET /5/on") >= 0) {
          Serial.println("GPIO 5 on");
          output5State = "on";
          digitalWrite(output5, HIGH);
        } else if (header.indexOf("GET /5/off") >= 0) {
          Serial.println("GPIO 5 off");
          output5State = "off";
          digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
        } else if (header.indexOf("GET /4/on") >= 0) {
          Serial.println("GPIO 4 on");
          output4State = "on";
          digitalWrite(output4, HIGH);
        } else if (header.indexOf("GET /4/off") >= 0) {
          Serial.println("GPIO 4 off");
          output4State = "off";
          digitalWrite(output4, LOW);
        }

      }

   void handle_NotFound(){
   server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
    }

   String SendHTML(float TempCstat,float Humiditystat, float  percentage){
    String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
    ptr +="<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
    // ptr +="<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2\" >\n";
   ptr +="<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Open+Sans:300,400,600\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n";
    ptr +="<title>ESP8266 Weather Report</title>\n";
    ptr +="<style>html { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; display: 
    block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;color: #333333;}\n";
    ptr +="body{margin-top: 50px;}\n";
    ptr +="h1 {margin: 50px auto 30px;}\n";
    ptr +=".side-by-side{display: inline-block;vertical-align: 
     middle;position: relative;}\n";
    ptr +=".humidity-icon{background-color: #3498db;width: 30px;height: 
    30px;border-radius: 50%;line-height: 36px;}\n";
     ptr +=".humidity-text{font-weight: 600;padding-left: 15px;font-size: 
     19px;width: 160px;text-align: left;}\n";
     ptr +=".humidity{font-weight: 300;font-size: 60px;color: #3498db;}\n";
     ptr +=".temperature-icon{background-color: #f39c12;width: 30px;height: 
     30px;border-radius: 50%;line-height: 40px;}\n";
     ptr +=".temperature-text{font-weight: 600;padding-left: 15px;font-size: 
     19px;width: 160px;text-align: left;}\n";
     ptr +=".temperature{font-weight: 300;font-size: 60px;color: 
     #f39c12;}\n";
     ptr +=".superscript{font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;position: 
     absolute;right: -20px;top: 15px;}\n";
     ptr +=".data{padding: 10px;}\n";
     ptr +="</style>\n";
     ptr +="<script>\n";
     ptr +="setInterval(loadDoc,200);\n";
     ptr +="function loadDoc() {\n";
     ptr +="var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();\n";
     ptr +="xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {\n";
     ptr +="if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {\n";
     ptr +="document.getElementById(\"webpage\").innerHTML 
     =this.responseText}\n";
     ptr +="};\n";
     ptr +="xhttp.open(\"GET\", \"/\", true);\n";
     ptr +="xhttp.send();\n";
     ptr +="}\n";
     ptr +="</script>\n";

     ptr +="</head>\n";
     ptr +="<body>\n";

     ptr +="<div id=\"webpage\">\n";

     ptr +="<h1>ESP8266 Weather Report</h1>\n";
     ptr +="<div class=\"data\">\n";
     ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side temperature-icon\">\n";
     ptr +="<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" 
     xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" 
     xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\n";
     ptr +="width=\"9.915px\" height=\"22px\" viewBox=\"0 0 9.915 22\" 
     enable-background=\"new 0 0 9.915 22\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n";
      ptr +="<path fill=\"#FFFFFF\" d=\"M3.498,0.53c0.377-0.331,0.877- 
      0.501,1.374-0.527C5.697-0.04,6.522,0.421,6.924,1.142\n";
      ptr+= 
       "c0.237,0.399,0.315,0.871,0.311,1.33C7.229,5.856,7.245,9.24,7.227,
        12.625c1.019,0.539,1.855,1.424,2.301,2.491\n";
      ptr +="c0.491,1.163,0.518,2.514,0.062,3.693c-0.414,1.102-1.24,2.038- 
      2.276,2.594c-1.056,0.583-2.331,0.743-3.501,0.463\n";
      ptr +="c-1.417-0.323-2.659-1.314-3.3-2.617C0.014,18.26- 
      0.115,17.104,0.1,16.022c0.296-1.443,1.274-2.717,2.58-3.394\n";
      ptr +="c0.013-3.44,0-6.881,0.007- 
      10.322C2.674,1.634,2.974,0.955,3.498,0.53z\"/>\n";
      ptr +="</svg>\n";
      ptr +="</div>\n";
      ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side temperature- 
      text\">Temperature</div>\n";
      ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side temperature\">";
      ptr +=(int)TempCstat;
      ptr +="<span class=\"superscript\">°C</span></div>\n";
      ptr +="</div>\n";  
      ptr +="<div class=\"data\">\n";
      ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side humidity-icon\">\n";
      ptr +="<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_2\" 
      xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" 
      xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\n\"; 
      width=\"12px\" height=\"17.955px\" viewBox=\"0 0 13 17.955\" enable- 
      background=\"new 0 0 13 17.955\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n";
      ptr +="<path fill=\"#FFFFFF\" 
     d=\"M1.819,6.217C3.139,4.064,6.5,0,6.5,0s3.363,4.064,4.681,6.217c1.793,
      2.926,2.133,5.05,1.571,7.057\n";
     ptr +="c-0.438,1.574-2.264,4.681-6.252,4.681c-3.988,0-5.813-3.107- 
     6.252-4.681C-0.313,11.267,0.026,9.143,1.819,6.217\"></path>\n";
     ptr +="</svg>\n";
     ptr +="</div>\n";
     ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side humidity-text\">Humidity</div>\n";
     ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side humidity\">";
     ptr +=(int)Humiditystat;
     ptr +="<span class=\"superscript\">%</span></div>\n";
     ptr +="</div>\n";

    //Buttons

     ptr +="<div class=\"data\">\n";
     ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side button-text\">Button</div>\n";
     ptr +="<div class=\"side-by-side Button\">";
     ptr +=" <p><a href=\"/5/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button></a> 
     </p>";
     // If the output5State is off, it displays the ON button       
        if (output5State=="off") {
          ptr +="<p><a href=\"/5/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button> 
       </a></p>";
        } else {
          ptr +="<p><a href=\"/5/off\"><button class=\"button 
        button2\">OFF</button></a></p>";
        } 
         // If the output4State is off, it displays the ON button       
        if (output4State=="off") {
          ptr +="<p><a href=\"/4/on\"><button class=\"button\">ON</button> 
         </a></p>";
        } else {
          ptr +="<p><a href=\"/4/off\"><button class=\"button 
          button2\">OFF</button></a></p>";
          } 
           ptr +="<span class=\"superscript\">%</span></div>\n";
           ptr +="</div>\n";
           ptr +="</div>\n";
           ptr +="</body>\n";
           ptr +="</html>\n";
           return ptr;
          }
```

Comment: Why are you searching for request parameters inside your generated response HTML?

Comment: Where shoulf I search !

Comment: @AlMa, did you read the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Write handlers for different URLs

```
server.on("/5/on", led5On); 
server.on("/5/off", led5off);
```

do you get the concept?

or you could write one handler `server.on("/setLED", setLED);`, if you would send `"/setLED?num=5&state=on"`. and then in `setLED` function get the parameters values as

```
String num = sever.arg("num");
String state = sever.arg("state");
```

see the SimpleAuthentication example